# Sending byte array to WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

Hello I tried all solutions from stackoverflow.com but it didn't work for me.

Here is my code

**WCF Service**:

```
public void SendImage(byte[] img, string filename)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(img);
    FileStream stream = new FileStream(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + filename, FileMode.Create);
    memoryStream.CopyTo(stream);
    stream.Close();
}
```

**Interface:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "sendImage")]
void SendImage(byte[] img, string filename);
```

Here is my **Web.Config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                propagateActivity="true" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="myUserTraceSource"
                switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="xml"
                type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                initializeData="Traces.svclog" />
        </sharedListeners>
    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <diagnostics wmiProviderEnabled="true">
            <messageLogging
                logEntireMessage="true"
                logMalformedMessages="true"
                logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
                logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
                maxMessagesToLog="3000"
                />
        </diagnostics>
            <services>
                <service name="WcfService1.RestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
                    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web">

                    </endpoint>
                </service>
            </services>
            <bindings>
                <!-- 
                    Following is the expanded configuration section for a BasicHttpBinding.
                    Each property is configured with the default value.
                    See the TransportSecurity, and MessageSecurity samples in the
                    Basic directory to learn how to configure these features.
                -->
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="Binding1" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                        sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                        openTimeout="00:10:00"
                        closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                        maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                        transferMode="Streamed"
                        messageEncoding="Text"
                        bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                        useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                        maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                    <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>    
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And my **app.config**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:55008/RestServiceImpl.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRestServiceImpl"
                contract="ServiceReference1.IRestServiceImpl"      name="BasicHttpBinding_IRestServiceImpl"/>
        </client>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRestServiceImpl"
                    hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                    sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    openTimeout="00:10:00"
                    closeTimeout="00:10:00"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                    transferMode="StreamedResponse"
                    messageEncoding="Text"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                    <security mode="None" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

My question is why I get:

> System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The remote server returned an unexpected response: (413) Request Entity Too Large. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
>     at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> Server stack trace: 
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory 1 factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
>     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>     at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>     at WpfApplication1.ServiceReference1.IRestServiceImpl.SendImage(Byte[] img, String filename)
>     at WpfApplication1.ServiceReference1.RestServiceImplClient.SendImage(Byte[] img, String filename) in C:\Users\lukgol\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfService1\WpfApplication1\Service References\ServiceReference1\Reference.cs:line 120
>     at WpfApplication1.MainWindow.buttonSendToServer_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\lukgol\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WcfService1\WpfApplication1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 97

When I run this code:

```
private void buttonSendToServer_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    imageCtrl.Source = null;
    ServiceReference1.RestServiceImplClient service = new ServiceReference1.RestServiceImplClient();
    foreach (MyBitmap bit in listBitmap)
    {
        string s;
        try
        {
            service.SendImage(bit.GetBytes(), bit.FileName);
        }
        catch (ProtocolException ex)
        {
            s = ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    service.Close();
}
```

Comment: Please include the size of the file you're trying to upload and any IIS configurations you've tried as well.

Comment: I also noticed your binding uses "text" and not "binary" for the encoding, which may be what you want. At first glance the other settings in your binding appear large enough to allow your file.

Comment: optionally you could inplement streaming in WCF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the WCF end (i.e., separate from IIS), you're not using the binding you defined in the service config file (`Binding1`):

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          contract="WcfService1.IRestServiceImpl" 
          behaviorConfiguration="web">
```

You specify the *type* of binding to use, but since you didn't specify the configuration to use, you will get the default settings for `basicHttpBinding`.  To specify the binding configuration, use the `bindingConfiguration` attribute, like this:

```
<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="Binding1"
          contract="WcfService1.IRestServiceImpl"
          behaviorConfiguration="web">
```

There could be other configurations to, but this is the most common reason from a *WCF* perspective.

Comment: Yes, great! I spend few hours to find solution. Thank You very much, now runs fantastic. Regards.